# Using UITapGestureRecognizer to show/hide menus

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, ibooks

I'm trying to find a good way to make a tap show/hide my menus, in the same way as iBooks. I set up UITapGestureRecognizer to do this, but unfortunately it means then that none of the buttons on the screen work. I know I can use

```
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

in order to allow the touches to go through, but then of course, both things happen and I can't cancel the menu show/hide.

Is there a way for me to stop the UITapGestureRecognizer from happening on certain buttons or actions? Or is there a better way of doing this in general?

Thanks very much in advance for any help you can give me!

:-Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case someone needs a little code to understand Joe's solution, you should first implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol (i.e `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`).

In the class that implements the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol, you have to implement `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch`. There, you can check if touch.view is a button. In my implementation, I only used a `return !([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]);` but you may need to extend this if you have other touch-enabled components in which you don't want to trigger your tap recognizer.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it (or someone else solved it for me) so I thought I'd share with you:

> Return NO from the delegate method
>   gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:
>   if touch.view is one of your buttons.